# Horde complains that Imp is not running

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, horde, imp

I'm a mostly-Windows guy tasked with setting up email on an Ubuntu 12.04 instance at AWS and hit the following error:

When I browse to Horde, after entering my administrative credentials, I get the error message:

> A fatal error has occurred
>
> imp is not activated.
>
> Details have been logged for the administrator.

I am following the following, quite detailed guide

http://www.exratione.com/2012/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1204-postfix-dovecot-mysql/

This is happening at Step 20, at the text *Now fire up you web browser and navigate to your server at http://mail.example.com/ to verify that you can log in as the configured administrative mail user.* (of course I used my actual domain).

**Questions**

- Where is Horde logging the "details"?
- Any thoughts on why this might happen?  I found Google hits suggesting that php5-mcrypt might be missing, but I verified it is installed and up-to-date in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1: Check the apache error logs. Specifically, the `error.log` file.

A2: If you used the long `conf.php` on the linked page as a template, **don't**. Something in that file might be causing the issue. Just copy `conf.php.dist` in the same directory over `conf.php`, and modify `conf.php` as you need.

Comment: Yeah, it was something about the provided conf.php.

Comment: In my case, it was just a chrome extension causing it. Worked fine in Incognito and other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not HordeMail it's Dovecot!

Try to use these paths in  `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf`

```
 ssl_cert = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
 ssl_key = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

the paths provided by the tutorial are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Careful following the instructions in http://www.exratione.com/2012/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1204-postfix-dovecot-mysql/. These instructions are missing lines in many of the configuration files beginning in section 20 where you configure Horde. The script for file /var/www/config/conf.php is missing all lines past line 170. This leaves you with a partially-configured system that does not work.

Comment: Can you point to the correct instructions, or give them here?

Comment: I'll email the author and see if he can post the updated files. I'll let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 0):

After following the guide and using the conf.php file provided, a solution that worked to get past this error was:

- Use the conf.php.dist as the conf.php
- Copy over the "sql" configuration section from the provided quite into the new conf.php
- Follow the remaining guide